# Get other shapes in R for geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, visualization

I need to replicate this exact visualisation but i can't find those shapes in R. How can I find, for example, the first shape from here which is square inside the square?

`ggplot(df, aes(x=x_column,y=y_column, shape=shape, color=shape))+geom_point(size=4)+scale_shape_manual(values=c(0:25))`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDG2h.png)
I implemented this code but the default values of shapes in R aren't the same as in sample plot

Comment: Not sure how to implement exactly those shapes but you can use unicode characters, e.g., `ggplot(data = tibble(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10)), mapping = aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point(shape = "\u25CC", size = 10)` and this package may be of help (https://github.com/GuangchuangYu/emojifont).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are standard shapes, but points are layered with different sizes.
Building on reference examples of
[Aesthetic specifications](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-specs.html#point) and [`geom_point()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_point.html#ref-examples)  :

```r
library(ggplot2)

shapes <- data.frame(
  shape = c(0:25),
  x = 0:25 %/% 5,
  y = -(0:25 %% 5)
)

ggplot(shapes, aes(x,y,shape = factor(shape))) +
  geom_point(size = 4) +
  geom_point(size = 8) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = 0:25, 
                     guide = guide_legend(ncol = 3, keyheight = 1.8)) +
  theme_void() +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>